# NoClassDefFoundError on Uber/Fat Jar created with SBT

Tags: scala, log4j, sbt, sbt-assembly

I am using `sbt assembly` plugin to create a `Uber/Fat` jar. But getting the following `Exception`

```
scala -cp ./target/scala-2.11/test.jar com.LoggingTest
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
```

I already have `log4j` as part of my dependency(refers `build.sbt` file below). Not sure why I am still getting the `NoClassDefFoundError`

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    name := "myproject",
    version := "1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.8",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-api" % "2.8",
        "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-core" % "2.8",
        "org.apache.logging.log4j" %% "log4j-api-scala" % "2.8"
    )
 )

// Adding scala style to compilation process
lazy val compileScalastyle = taskKey[Unit]("compileScalastyle")
compileScalastyle := org.scalastyle.sbt.ScalastylePlugin.scalastyle.in(Compile).toTask("").value
(compile in Compile) <<= (compile in Compile) dependsOn compileScalastyle


assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("javax", "servlet", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("javax", "activation", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("javax", "el", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("org", "apache", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "google", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "esotericsoftware", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "codahale", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "yammer", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("org", "jboss", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("io", "netty", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case "about.html" => MergeStrategy.rename
  case "META-INF/ECLIPSEF.RSA" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "META-INF/mailcap" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "META-INF/mimetypes.default" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "META-INF/jboss-beans.xml" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "plugin.properties" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "log4j.properties" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "project.properties" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties" => MergeStrategy.last
  case x =>
      val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
      oldStrategy(x)
}
```

Here is the complete content of the plugin definitions file `$PROJECT_HOME/project/plugins.sbt`

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.3")
addSbtPlugin("org.scalastyle" %% "scalastyle-sbt-plugin" % "0.8.0")
```

I also `unzipped` the jar and found that class(`org.apache.log4j.logger.Logger`) is not available in the Jar. I was expecting the Class to be available in the Jar as `log4j` has been added as part of `sbt` dependency. I did find the class `org.apache.`**logging**`.log4j.Logger` though

PS: I am also executing the `jar` using `spark-submit` for some of the Classes(as I am using `spark` api for some computation) and it works without any issues

Comment: Can you also show the `sbt-assembly` plugin settings for your project?

Comment: Also, I assume that you created the `test.jar` using the `sbt assemble` task? Either way, a _JAR_ file is just a _zip_ file with a different extension. If you copy it and rename it `test.zip` you can unzip it and examine its contents. Given the error you're seeing, I expect that you will not find an `org/apache/log4j/Logger.class` file in the extracted contents.

Comment: @MikeAllen yes, I did create the Jar using `sbt assembly` command(not `sbt assemble`). I have also updated the question with my complete `sbt` file content(including merge strategy) as well as the content of `plugins.sbt`. Like you have said, The jar file do not have the class. Wondering what might have caused this, considering I have added `log4j` as part of `sbt` dependency

Comment: Whoops! You're right, it is `sbt assembly`. Sorry for any confusion. I'm just taking a look at your settings now...

Comment: the "merge strategy" is used for files with each _JAR_ file that have the same name, and that will therefore clash when merged into the resulting fat JAR file. I don't think you need to list every file - particularly if there's no chance of a clash. Also, I think that any assembly settings will have to be included in the root project (either as common settings, or just relocated to be under that project's settings) in order to take effect. Finally, there's no instruction to name the output `test.jar`, so which file are you copying to create that file?

Comment: When you run `sbt assembly`, what is the output? You should see statements such as `[info] Including: <jar file name>` for each _JAR_ file merged into the fat _JAR_ file produced.

Comment: @MikeAllen Finally I am able to find out the reason. I am using log4j2(not log4j 1.2), But using the log4j 1.2 to create the Logger(org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(*)). I should be using LogManager.getLogger(*) instead to create the Logger. I also changed the log4j.properties to log4j2.properties(the format also differs vis-a-vis log4j.properties). This resolved my issue

Comment: Might be useful for someone who has a mix of Spark & Non-spark code: I have to revert back to log4j 1.2 instead of log4j 2.0 as spark do not support log4j 2 and my project has a mix of both Spark & Non-Spark Code